# Rails 4 : Custom routes, multiple edit forms for a single model

Tags: ruby, http, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a Rails 4 app, with a Thing model that have 3 attributes : attr_1, attr_2, attr_3.

I would like to have two edit forms :

- the first one would update attr_1 and attr_2
- the second one would only update attr_3

I have written four methods in my things_controller.rb :

```
def edit
  #edit form for attr_1 & attr_2
end

def edit_attr_3
  #edit form for attr_3 only
end

def update
  #update attr_1 & attr_2
end

def update_attr_3
  #update attr_3 only
end
```

And here's my routes.db

```
resources :things do 
  member do
    get :edit_attr_3
    put :update_attr_3
  end
end
```

Now, GET to both edit views work (/things/:id/edit and /things/:id/edit_attr_3) but on submit, the thing#update form is called both times (thing#update_attr_3 is never called)

How can I proceed to get thing#edit_attr_3 action linked to thing#update_attr_3 please ?

---

### EDIT :

Answer, thanks to [Ross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732240/ross) & [Steve Klein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3311657/steve-klein) :

In my views, I am using [bootstrap_form_for](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms). Usually the :url parameter is optional, as standard edit/update are linked by convention. In the case of custom edit or update actions, it is necessary to specify the update path.

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @thing, url: update_attr_3_thing_path(@thing) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post the `edit_attr_3` view (called `edit_attr_3.html.erb` I assume)?  Not sure what is happening but you can specify the controller path with the `:url` option in your form.

Comment: I am posting the edit_attr_3 view for other people facing with same issue, but you are right Steve,  the :url option was missing in my form. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted @Sag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing the code for your form... but if you are using `form_for` then the route it will map to the update action in both cases (with an object that is not a new object).

To make it work with your unique update action, you will have to specify the url that `form_for` should use. Something like:

```
<%= form_for @thing, url: things_update_attr_3_path(@thing) do |f| %>
  # other form stuff .......
```

You can use `bundle exec rake routes` at the command prompt to see what your current routes are, so that you now what route helper to use with form for.

Comment: That was it. I was not specifying the custom update_attr_3 url in my edit_attr_3 form, as with standard show/edit actions it is not necessary. Problem solved ! Thanks. :)